# bsd sed and double quotes

Tags: sed, bsd

Consider the file `test.txt`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"
```

using GNU sed version 4.2.1 (on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS), I can extract foo.h, bar.h and baz.h with:

```
SHELL$) sed -n -e 's:^\s*\#include\s*"\(.*\)".*:\1:p' test.txt
foo.h
bar.h
baz.h
```

using BSD sed (on Mac OS X lion), and modifying the above command, I can extract foo.h, bar.h and baz.h, but with double quotes:

```
SHELL) sed -n -e 's:^\s*\#include\s*\(.*\).*:\1:p' test.txt
 "foo.h"
 "bar.h"
 "bar.h"
```

How can to extract names without the quotes with BSD sed? The output of theses commands are empty:

```
SHELL) sed -n -e 's:^\s*\#include\s*"\(.*\)".*:\1:p' test.txt
SHELL) sed -n -e 's:^\s*\#include\s*\"\(.*\)\".*:\1:p' test.txt
```

Comment: For a portable workaround, just remove double quotes from input (`tr '"' ' '`) before applying your sed command.

Answer (score 2):

BSD `sed` (unsurprisingly, really) doesn't support the `\s` Perlism -- it is interpreted as just a literal `s`. Try this instead;

```
 sed -n -e 's!^[[:space:]]*\#include[[:space:]]*"\(.*\)".*!\1!p' test.txt
```

The character class `[[:space:]]` should work in all POSIX regex implementations. (Other `sed`s may or may not want backslashes before grouping parentheses.)